# When can I tag as [faq-proposed]?

Tags: support, tags, meta

The [guidance for `faq-proposed`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq-proposed/info) simply says *how* to make something into a [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed), but I am looking for guidance for *when* to do this.

Case in point, I [created a question + answer post last week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors) which so far has received a fair amount of positive attention ([Nice Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question?userid=874188) and [Nice Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=874188) within a few hours; [Good Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question?userid=874188) pretty quickly, [Good Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/24/good-answer?userid=874188) after a couple of days).

Now I'm wondering if this would be suitable for [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) and more generally what sort of criteria and timetables are recommended or expected around this tag.

My question and answer pair was quite specifically created to address a frequently asked question. Is this sufficient for [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed)?

If not, what sort of delay and/or popularity criteria would be required to add this tag and the associated decorations?

Comment: I propose that this question become an [faq-proposed] once it's answered.

Comment: @DavyM Doesn't look frequently asked to me.

Answer (score 12):

I haven't done this myself on meta, but it seems fairly straight-forward. Add the [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed), then also flag the question and ask for a moderator to turn it into community wiki.

What you should do however, is to clean up the question a bit. I think the title should be "Problematic questions about *text* decoding errors", not to mix it up with other forms of decoding, such as protocol decoding, decryption, disassembly etc.

FAQ entries should have a high quality question and not just high quality answers. In this case, the question could be improved with some real examples. There are some examples in the answer - these should ideally be mirrored from the question. Such as, `<here's the hex dump>`, what format is this and how do I decode it. And then the answer uses the same example. Since it is clear that the question is a FAQ entry, you could ask several questions in one with different examples.

However, I am not convinced that this should be a FAQ entry on meta, which is what [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) is for. The answer is technical and as such I think it rather belongs on the main site. Perhaps as part of the [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) tag wiki. It mainly aims to address the poster of the problematic question, rather than the person moderating it. I think you should rather seek to migrate this to the main site instead, where it can get more attention and do more good. It could then perhaps be used as a canonical dupe.

Comment: I quite purposely posted on Meta because "how to ask" questions should not be on the main site. I hesitantly agree that perhaps this could be refactored into "how do I troubleshoot text encoding errors" and posted on the main site.

Comment: @tripleee How to ask doesn't belong there indeed, but technical FAQ does, even if it is broader than we would normally allow a question to be. Such FAQs can be used for dupe-hammer purposes.